# Family Settings on Microsoft?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security

Over the past couple of days I've kept receiving this message on my Windows 10 Laptop, "Your family can see reports of what you do on this device..." Last time I checked my family never put any sort of restriction on my PC.

So I decided to go on Microsoft's family safety website and my cousin is added as a family member for no reason. How can I delete him from my family, as he sees what I do on my PC now?

There is no remove button on the family website or in settings tab.
[image: No remove button on.]
[image: No remove button here, either. Just says another adult.]

Comment: First of all go to Services.msc and disable to the Windows Live Family Safety service as well as the Parental Controls service. Until this is fixed, they should at least not be able to monitor you

Comment: Do you have authorization to remove this family member?  Are you a child under a restricted account?

Comment: I cannot tell @Ramhound as it does say I'm the administrator.

Comment: @Ramhound Nope. It just states these are your family members.

Comment: @Asker123 - You didn't answer my second question.  You having the ability to change it on, is separate from, you being authorized to do it.

Comment: @Ramhound No I do not have the ability and I do not know if I am authorized.